# SQL Server SELECT Performance with JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

in SQL Server, I would like to know if there is any performance difference between doing this (A)...

```
SELECT a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.IDfield = b.IDfield
```

and this (B)...

```
SELECT a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.IDfield = b.IDfield
```

Well, this is a simplified example. I am working with some 4 joins and I have been doing it like in example B. Is it a bad practice? I simply find it better to write, better to read, but won`t do it any more if it is worse in terms of performance. Of course, I cannot do left joins, right joins this way, but they are not the case in the queries I am doing. Thanks.

Comment: The simple answer would be to profile it.

Comment: @rein - Agreed! You never know until you profile it. I've seen some cases in which they behave differently.

Answer (score 6):

No there is no difference - since in the end, both queries will be a INNER JOIN between tables A and B on the `a.IDfield = b.IDfield` criteria.

But query (A) is the much preferred way of expressing your intent - always use this style when writing new queries! It's the style as described in the ANSI SQL standard, too - so you're definitely better off using this style whenever possible.

Marc

Comment: The B syntax that shown will not be supported at some point.  So get used to writing the A version.  Also in some cases (I can't remember what) the B syntax can production different results.  I think it has something to do with right joins.

Comment: @MrDenny: good point - and yet another good reason not to start getting used to that syntax! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience, I'd say that it depends!

SQL Server Optimizer is a real mysterious **thing**. Ideally, there's no difference between the two syntaxes; but, you should use the `JOIN` keyword, in practice, as Marc said.

Depending on the runtime conditions, SQL Server Optimizer **MAY** make the second query to run faster than the first one or vice versa. It all depends. You can use the Query Execution Plan to **REALLY** determine which query performs optimally.

Comment: I don't think it depends in this case - in both cases, there's a simple and straightforward criteria (a.IDfield = b.IDfield) and both will be straight INNER JOINs, really.

Comment: You are correct, they both are same. But, generally, its a better practice to see the query execution plan to see which query performs more better.

Comment: Agreed - but this sample is just too easy to even bother having to look at an execution plan :-)

Comment: Yep. But as per the OP - Well, this is a simplified example. I am working with some 4 joins and I have been doing it like in example B - So, you are correct for the simplified scenario, but for 4 joins, profiling will help. Using `JOIN` keyword is the way to go tho.

Answer (score 1):

I would under no circumstances ever use the second syntax. It is very prone to accidental cross joins when you have a large number of joins. The first is also far clearer for maintenance. The left and right join syntax that goes along with that style do not work correctly in SQl Server and are being discontinued.

In my opinion it is a very poor practice to use the second syntax. And it's only 17 years out of date besides.

Answer (score 1):

With all other things being equal (same db, same indexes, same statistics, MDOP settings), performance wise there is no difference in the two queries.

You can see this by executing:

SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON
GO

SELECT a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.IDfield = b.IDfield
GO

SELECT a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1FROM table1 a, table2 bWHERE a.IDfield = b.IDfield
GO

after executing the above you will see the execution plan is indeed identical for the two queries.

Alternatively you can highlight the statement(s) in management studio, right click, and select "include actual execution plan" to see a graphical representation of the same thing.